# deixar a imagem de fundo cheia no css

Tags: javascript, html, css

nao estou conseguindo deixar minha pagina de contato no portifolio com a imagem de fundo completa.

body{
background-image: url('https://images2.alphacoders.com/480/thumb-1920-480530.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
body {
background-image: url(https://images2.alphacoders.com/480/thumb-1920-480530.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
margin: 0px;
```

}

Tenta utilizar isso, assim vai deixar teu body full screen.
o height 100vh faz com que ele preencha totalmente, normalmente o body vem com margin, então ali estamos eliminando a margin que pode afetar no fullscreen do body, e assim sua imagem fica completinha.